# How to deploy assemblies conditionally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I build extensions for a 3rd party application.  We do not have access to the source code.  Visual studio has a post build command to copy files to said program's assembly directory.

```
copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb "$(ProgramDropDir)"
copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll "$(ProgramDropDir)"
```

When the program launches it loads the assemblies (actually they are loaded when required, I think this is because of JIT compilation).  Our application consists of 49 assemblies.  Deploying them all is quite slow.  I can get around the slow build by building at the project level.  This builds only  referenced assemblies.  That's still problematic 95% of the time. Usually, only 1 assembly has actually changed...yet all are copied.

How can this process be improved?  Ideally...

> A.  Deploy assemblies only when they changed. 
>   B.  Build only when a project file has changed. 
>   C.  copy only when I plan to run the main application.  E.G. Do not copy when running a unit test.
>   D.  The build fails when the 3rd party app is running.  I have to close the app.  Which means I have to re-login to the app and wait for it to load (its a slow loading beast).

I own TFS2010.  If absolutely necessary, I am open to new tools.

Comment: would something like NuGet[http://nuget.org/] work? IE: Only update assemblies NuGet version when an update is made, and simply pull the latest NuGet package when an update is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** You can use [RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to do this. By default, RoboCopy will only copy a file if the source and destination have different timestamps or different file sizes.

You can also use RoboCopy task in [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) if you want to do it with MSBuild.

**B.** If you are using a CI server you can use poll SCM mechanism that starts a build whenever a change is made in SCM.

I am not sure what you mean with the last one. No builds are triggered when you 'run' the application or some unit test.

Comment: The Post build handles the copy operation.  I do not want a copy to occur at all when I run a unit test.  But because its a post build operation, it runs on every build.  The copy is just for the sake of the 3rd party application.  So only when I plan to test inside the 3rd party application do I want a copy (the postbuild action) to occur.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey How do you run your unit tests? They should be using already compiled assemblies and should not require any build. Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: I know NUnit references assemblies in such a way.  I use MSTest.  The unit test project references the assemblies that need to be tested just like any other visual studio project.  When the tests start, the references are built. Even if I used NUnit I still need to build the assembly before I can test it, which means the Post-build operation still fires.